# TensorFlow не видит Cuda

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda

Установил CUDA toolkit и CUDNN, добавил в PATH, но данная функция все равно возвращает **False**.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
```

Пользуюсь JupyterNotebook из дистрибутива Anaconda.
ОС - Windows 11. CUDA v11. CUDNN v8.7.

Команда `nvcc -V` в PowerShell работает, выводит версию CUDA.

Comment: А посмотрите что внутри ноутбука выдаст `!set`, правильный ли там `PATH`? И `!python -V` посмотрите, та ли версия питона запускается. В общем, посмотрите окружение из самого юпитер ноутбука, всё ли там нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Долго мучился с похожей проблемой. Переустановил всё что можно и CUDA, и Python, и библиотеки, и разные версии всего, что только можно.  В итоге на одном сайте, нашёл информацию как проверить версию установленного драйвера CUDA https://russianblogs.com/article/8204984484/.
Если кратко, то в трее двойным щелчком открываете настройки Nvidia

[image: Скриншот трея]

Затем в левом нижнем углу нажимаем информация о системе

[[image: Панель Nvidia]

Переходим на вкладку Компоненты и смотрим версию драйвера CUDA

[image: Версия драйвера CUDA]

Поскольку я не так давно обновился, то отображается стоит 12.0. И видимо поэтому при установке более ранней CUDA tensorflow не запускался. После этого скачал и установил CUDA Toolkit 12.0 и tensorflow начал нормально видеть GPU.